# Position absolute but relatif

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

Currently I use this CSS to place a div (.child_bottom) at the bottom of its parent and another div above it (.child) because I know the height of (.child_bottom).

The parent at a variable height.

```css
.parent
{
  position:relative;
}

.child
{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:250px;
}

.child_bottom
{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  height:250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child"></div>
  
  <div class="child_bottom"></div>

</div>
```

But I would like to obtain the same thing with a variable height of .child_bottom, how to do?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Will there ever be content before `.child`?

Comment: No content before .child but .parent has a variable height.

Comment: flexbox is the way to go .. cannot find the  duplicate ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using flex would allow you to remove all of the absolute positioning:

```css
.parent {
  height: 400px;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.child {
  background: green;
}

.child_bottom {
  background: orange;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child">CHILD</div>

  <div class="child_bottom">CHILD_BOTTOM</div>

</div>
```

If you did wish to add content before `.child`, remove the `justify-content` and make this content `flex: 1`:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* justify-content: flex-end; */
  height: 400px;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.child {
  background: green;
}

.child_bottom {
  background: orange;
  height: 250px;
}

.other_content {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="other_content">
    OTHER_CONTENT (Fills the space)
  </div>

  <div class="child">CHILD</div>

  <div class="child_bottom">CHILD_BOTTOM</div>

</div>
```